# Can ADFS as SAML2.0 SP have more than one entity id, depending on RPs?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

Basically I have a scenario which requires that the same ADFS SAML SP has two separate SAML entity id, can this be done? How? Do I need to have separate RP for each entity ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use claims rules to change the identifier before issuing claims. But the federation metadata will always reveal the real true entityid as nzpcmad said.

So if you federate with AD FS without using the metadata endpoint and manually specify the entityID and endpoints, you can use claims rules to achieve this.

Customers with Office 365 have experience with this. If one AD FS is used to federate more than one domain in use (on O365/Azure AD) then a claims rule is used to change the http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/issuerid before issuance.

here is the relevant rule as used in O365 and Azure AD. The below rule extracts the UPN suffix and uses this to make an identifier like http://domain.com/adfs/services/trust/ (where domain.com is UPN suffix as defined in AD for the user)

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/issuerid", Value = regexreplace(c.Value, ".+@(?<domain>.+)", "http://${domain}/adfs/services/trust/"));
```

So if you add claims rules to your relevant RP trust as deemed necessary you can either use default AD FS identifier or make it appear as something else.

Comment: Interesting! Where does the domain value come from - as in ${domain}?

Comment: I edited the post as some chars were stripped out. Regex should be clearer now.

Comment: Yup - I thought regex groups were involved somehow!

Comment: Ok this seems intersting but I wonder if there is a way to add two Identity Providers IdP with the same certificate on ADFS I get an error

Answer (score 0):

The standard ADFS entity ID in the metadata is:

entityID="http://xxx/adfs/services/trust"

There is only one and it is actually the ADFS URL.

There is no way to change the metadata as well.

You would need two separate ADFS instances.